# How to open a file named index.php which is in htdocs/project1 folder in xampp?

Tags: php

I have one folder named project1 in htdocs folder path is "C:\xampp\htdocs\project1" and i have created index.php file in "project1" folder. How to open this file in browser or in local host?

Comment: localhost/project1/index.php

Comment: I have tried it , but it doesn't worked..

Comment: be sure your server is running.

Comment: what did you get? what do you mean by "it dosen't worked"?

Comment: ok,got it...it works.....thanks buddies....

Comment: start server access localhost and select your folder

Answer (score 8):

You can use:

```
http://localhost/project1
```

or

```
http://127.0.0.1/project1
```

in the address bar of your browser.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't access it via

```
http://localhost/project1
```

then open XAMPP control panel and make sure Apache,MYSQL (and any other you require) are running (have a green tick to the left of them).

If they don't then click 'Start' to begin running them. It should then work.